# what is i in factoring equations and how do i understand and apply it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am currently in Advanced Algebra-ii and we are working with polynomials however I did not understand the lesson where we learned about the number i or how to apply it when factoring or, in general, using equations. so, my question today is, how does i work? What does it mean? how do I use it in an equation or while factoring?

Comment: $i$ is a square root of $-1$, i.e. it satisfies $i^2=-1$. It can, for instance, allow you to factor a **sum** of squares. $$x^2+4 = x^2-(-1)4=x^2-i^2\cdot 2^2= x^2-(2i)^2=(x-2i)(x+2i)$$.

Comment: $i$ is a [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Answer (score 2):

The letter $i$ represents $\sqrt{-1}$. The formal definition is $i^2 = -1$. It is used in factoring to factor a sum of squares. The formula is:
$a^2 + b^2 = (a + bi)(a - bi)$
To prove it, I will use LHS-RHS.
LHS = $a^2 + b^2$, RHS = $(a+bi)(a-bi)$
$(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+abi-bia-bi^2$
$(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2-bi^2$
Because $i^2 = -1$, we can simplify the expression a little further
$(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2-b(-1)$
$(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$
LHS = RHS
There are also many other things you can do with $i$. The number $i$ is actually a *complex number*, which is also known as an *imaginary number*. Have you ever tried to solve a quadratic that does not touch the x-axis at all? You would get a negative square root, because $b^2 - 4ac$, the discriminant, is less than $0$. But with the other part of the entire number system, the *imaginary numbers*, you can find the *complex roots*. Have you ever wondered why the fundamental theorem of algebra is not always "true"? Just in case you are wondering, the fundamental theorem of algebra is this:
Every polynomial equation that can be written in the form $a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + a_2x^{n-2} + ... + a_{n-2}x^2 + a_{n-1}x^1 + a_nx^0 = 0$ has $n$ roots.
So, for example, every equation of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ must have $2$ roots, no exceptions. "But sometimes there are no roots", you say. If there are no real roots, then there will be $2$ complex roots.
For example, the equation $x^2 - 3x + 4$ has no real roots. The quadratic formula gives us the equation $x = \frac{10 ± \sqrt{-7}}{2}.$How would we simplify the $\sqrt{-7}$? Just recall that $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x} * \sqrt{y}$. So $\sqrt{-7} = \sqrt{7} * \sqrt{-1}$, which equals $\sqrt{7}i$. So the two roots of $x^2 - 3x + 4$ are $\frac{10 ± \sqrt{7}i}{2}$, which can be simplified to $5 ± \frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2}$.
There is actually a formula for figuring out the complex roots that is very similar to the quadratic formula we are familiar with today, with one slight alteration. The formula is:
$\frac{-b±i\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$
Where would I graph this, you ask? This brings up to an entirely new coordinate system, the *complex plane*.
To visually graph and identify the complex roots, we have to work in $3$-D coordinates. A new $i$ axis has to be added. Imagine the $y$ axis actually sticking up toward the "sky", and the $x$ and the $i$ axis traveling on the "floor" in different directions. These all intersect at the origin $(0,0,0)$. We would have to imagine that there is a plane running along the $x$ and $y$ axes, and graph $y = x^2-3x+4$ on that plane. To see the complex roots, we must "flip" the parabola so that it opens downward, and rotate it $90$ degrees so that the parabola is "facing" the $i$ axis to see the complex roots. I cannot explain this well without a visual, so just do a simple Google search on this topic. Here is a direct link to a good resource that talks about everything I mentioned here:
http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1034&context=mathmidexppap
I hope this answer helped you a bit :)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

$i=\sqrt{-1}$. The precise definition is $i^2 = -1$. When you allow complex numbers - that is, numbers of the form $a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real numbers, any polynomial of order $n$ with complex coefficients has $n$ roots over the complex numbers (this is the fundamental theorem of algebra). The complex numbers are the [algebraic closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of the real numbers (here is the definition of [algebraically closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) and some examples).